# CAssetManager.basePath "/assets" is invalid. Please make sure the directory exists and is writable by the Web server process.?

Tags: yii

When I run my YII Project on server , I got this error.

```
CException

CAssetManager.basePath "/var/www/html/v2/assets" is invalid. Please make sure the   directory exists and is writable by the Web server process.

/var/www/html/v2/yii/framework/web/CAssetManager.php(116)

104     }
105 
106     /**
107      * Sets the root directory storing published asset files.
108      * @param string $value the root directory storing published asset files
109      * @throws CException if the base path is invalid
110      */
111     public function setBasePath($value)
112     {
113         if(($basePath=realpath($value))!==false && is_dir($basePath) &&   is_writable($basePath))
114             $this->_basePath=$basePath;
115         else
116             throw new CException(Yii::t('yii','CAssetManager.basePath "{path}" is  invalid. Please make sure the directory exists and is writable by the Web server process.',
117                 array('{path}'=>$value)));
118     }
119 
120     /**
121      * @return string the base url that the published asset files can be accessed.
122      * Note, the ending slashes are stripped off. Defaults to '/AppBaseUrl/assets'.
123      */
124     public function getBaseUrl()
125     {
126         if($this->_baseUrl===null)
127         {
128             $request=Yii::app()->getRequest();
```

I do Not know ,how to resolve it?Please Explain solution of it?

This is my Project Structure

```
assets
protected <-- Yii app
js
css
yii
```

Comment: If `/var/www/html/v2/assets` exists then it's not writable by webserver user. If `/var/www/html/v2/assets` is not `assets` directory of your project then your application is configured improperly.

Comment: what should I do now?

Comment: If directory exists you should grant write permissions to web server process like Manquer wrote. Also `protected/runtime` directory must be created and be writable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assets folder should be writable by your web server process. Usually it is www-data if on apache configured by default.
You can either add the user to the folder group with '+w' permission modifications

Alternatively just modify the permissions to 777 as assets folder will only contain your js and css files which will be exposed to the public anyway
from your root directory

```
chmod 777 -R ./assets
```

You will also face the same issue with runtime and data/auth.php(*if app is configured for using Yii auth roles*), you can do similar suitable modifications there as well

**UPDATE::** Additional Settings for PHP < 5.4 is required if safe-mode flags are set ( this was depreciated in 5.4 ) refer to http://php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php on how to configure safe-mode settings in your php.ini file. Either you can set the flags fully off or exclude the directories in question. ( This step is not needed if you have added www-data(*your web-process*) to your group as the gid will then match automatically

Comment: Big coincidence I have this exact error and that your answer is recent. Changing the permissions worked but led to another error: `copy() [<a href='function.copy'>function.copy</a>]: SAFE MODE Restriction in effect. The script whose uid/gid is 219804/219804 is not allowed to access /f5/<my-site>/public/assets/27ff0fb6 owned by uid/gid 25000/25000`. The odd thing is, I don't have an assets sub-folder called `27ff0fb6`

Comment: You are using PHP version < 5.4 and also have set the safe mode flags to check for uid(userId)/gid(groupId) while allowing permissions in addition to system file permission levels. Refer to this page for details on how to use/configure safe mode http://php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php