# CAssetManager.basePath is invalid

Tags: yii

my web application perfectly running and then.
i'm jsut move that from one sever to other and i got this

CAssetManager.basePath "home/posococo/public_html/rims_new/assets" is invalid. Please make sure the directory exists and is writable by the Web server process.

i search a lot but not able to fix it.

some of say to change assets to 777.

after that i got

copy() [function.copy]: SAFE MODE Restriction in effect. The script whose uid is 2274 is not allowed to access /home/posococo/public_html/rims_new/assets/d4977f2b owned by uid 99

i do create new folder named 'd4977f2b'

i repeat my this process for 4 to 5 folder.

finally my aplication run.
but without css files from assets

how to fix it please help.

Comment: did you try "/home/posococo/public_html/rims_new/assets" ?

Comment: try "/home/posococo/public_html/rims_new/assets"? how i try that

Comment: Did you already try to delete all assets in the assets directory ?

Comment: yes i do that jacko07 but it give me same error. like yii create folder 'd4977f2b' by it's self

Comment: PHP is running in safe mode and if you can get your hosting service to switch that off, you should be fine. Otherwise, take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

First, note that the reason for the error you're getting is that your PHP installation is running in safe mode.

Here's a solution I got from the [Official Yii Forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/406-php-safe-mode/)

> To solve problem. Transfer your locally created assets folder with it's contents to server using ftp. This will ensure hosted assets folder and it's contents have appropriate owner/group id.
>   With everything else setup correctly look at assets error message displayed on screen. Using error example above.
>   Open your hosted assets folder on server, you should see two sets of folders distinguishable by uid. Open the folders with uid not 99 and search for one containing the right js files.
>   When files found, rename that folder to 87675fa2 based on our example. Then grant the folder and subfolders 777 permissions.
>   This should now work. Just repeat the process for the other assets related errors. The same solution should be applied if you get a mkdir() problem too related to assets.

Comment: thanks for your replay, can you plz explain this - 'you should see two sets of folders distinguishable by uid. Open the folders with uid not 99 and search for one containing the right js files. When files found, ' in detail

Comment: Basically, if you can't get PHP not to run in safe mode, you'd need to upload all your asset files yourself. Use your FTP application to upload your assets folder to your remote server thereby making you the owner of the assets folder.That way, you shouldn't have any problems

Comment: i already turned off my safe mode, just i want to know how i can find exact match of my uid 99 folder or how find aright js file for that

Comment: what FTP client are you using?

Comment: When you look at the "Owner/Group" column of the file-list, you should see the id of both the owner/group of a file or folder

Comment: What's the owner/group of your other php scripts?

Comment: it's 2274 2263 for others assets folders which i uploaded from my local sever

Comment: Delete the one that says 99 99 and upload one from your local server

Comment: but how i know which one upload, the folder with 99 99 and the folder in my local server is not match/ the new folder have totally different number then existing one.

Comment: Okay look at it this way: When your application uses some yii widgets, it's assets are published and (I think) whatever the machine your app is deployed on, the name of the asset folders are always the same. So, what I recommend is, run your app exhaustively on your local machine so that all assets are published. Then delete the asset folder on your remote server and upload the one from your local machine.

Comment: i do that but it create another new folder '64d1404d' with 99 99.    sry but it not works.

Comment: check out this post, it's solved but i'm not understand that.-         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20009689/cassetmanager-basepath-assets-is-invalid-please-make-sure-the-directory-exis

Comment: solved, Thanks @regingprodigy you help a lot to find solution.